# My Landmark Puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, knowledge, geography

After travelling around the world and returning home, I opened my passport to admire my stamps.

Five individual pieces of paper fell to the floor:

[image]

I must have picked them up somewhere, but I can't remember where...

---

**Hint #1**

> All of these pieces have printing on one side only.

**Hint #2**

> Some of the edges appear to be carefully torn.

Comment: The triangles are the wrong shape to make up a QR code... Am I meant to resize them? Based on the fact that you said they were "pieces of paper," that suggests to me that they would already be the proper size.

Comment: @phroureo I don't know what to say without giving it away. Everything is the 'proper size'. You might need to think differently.

Comment: I recommend leaving the image linked, as having access to the image for manipulation may be needed by some in attempting to solve the puzzle, and being able to click through to the individual file is rather helpful.

Comment: @feelinferrety I'm not sure it makes a difference but I've reverted the edit if it helps others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer

> You were in Giza, Egypt, at the [Pyramid of Khafre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_Khafre)?

Because

> The four black and white pieces of papers seem to be parts of a QR code, but they appear skewed. However, if you stand them up along their hypotenuse edges and, using the black square as a base, lean them against one another so that the 4 corners come together [to form a pyramid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11XMn.png), the intent becomes apparent. When viewed from above, the code is now readable, and scanning it with a mobile device, we find it decodes to `+2`.
>
>  The shape implies that we should be looking at pyramids, and I guess that the last hint is either to imply there's more than 2 pyramids (but that would be better hinted by `2+`), or, more likely that the precise location is the "2nd" pyramid, hence the Pyramid of Khafre, since it is known as "The Second Pyramid" and is the second-tallest and second-largest pyramid of Giza.

Comment: It's possible to solve the puzzle with just the five pieces in physical form, that means no resizing is required.

Comment: Congratulations! There was also _another_ meaning to the hidden code, which would have helped you find the answer if you hadn't already.

Comment: I don't understand your answer the way you've worded it. Can you specify what you mean or add visual aids?

Comment: I rewrote it, I hope it makes more sense. English isn't my native language so .. :/

Comment: I have added an edit to include an illustration to help visualise the answer.

Comment: @DamienBannerot The '+' was a deliberate reference to something else that would help you find the right area... or zone.