# My Landmark Puzzle II

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, geography

It can be hard to keep track of the places you visit when you travel the world, for some people numbers can be easier to remember than words.

I kept a note of the last place I visited:

[image: 43.00° 10.00° 3.79°]

> 43°
>   10°
>   3.97°

With these three numbers alone I can remember where I visited.

Can you tell me *where* I was, as well as *when* (the last year) I could have visited the *same place* if these three numbers added together were equal to 58.5°?

---

**Important Notes**

> There is nothing remarkable about the notebook apart from those three numbers.
>
> This puzzle is entirely solvable without seeing the [previous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/56499/244).

**Hint #1**

> To solve the puzzle you must first figure out *where* I was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The place you visited is

> [The Leaning Tower of Pisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa)

Because

> The location of the Tower of Pisa is roughly [43.72°N, 10.4°E](https://www.google.com/maps?ll=43.723056,10.396389&q=43.723056,10.396389&hl=en&t=h&z=15) to which your first two numbers give an approximation. The third number is, I believe, the approximate angle of the slant of the tower

The numbers added would have been 58.5

> Prior to restoration work completed in 2001, when the previous leaning angle was approximately 5.5°. The tower itself was closed to the public on January 7, 1990 for this restoration to take place so the last year you could have visited the tower itself would have been **1990**.

Comment: Congratulations! I wrote a little bit more about [how the puzzle is solved as well as an illustration](https://i.imgur.com/loYoVE9.png).